# Не работает интернационализация после переноса на сервер Django+Apache2+mod_wsgi

Tags: python-3.x, django

Добрый день подскажите в чем дело, после переезда на хостинг перестала работать интернационализация. Сервер Ububntu16.04+Apache2+mod_wsgi. В error.log  такая лабуда :

> [Sun Jan 28 18:52:18.784715 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8202:tid 139867517064960] http://mysite.ru/ru/uthuser/login/
>   [Sun Jan 28 18:52:20.463548 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8202:tid 139867517064960] http://mysite.ru/ru/uthuser/login/
>   [Sun Jan 28 18:52:20.463586 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8202:tid 139867517064960] /en/
>   [Sun Jan 28 18:52:20.463641 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8202:tid 139867517064960] /ru/
>   [Sun Jan 28 18:52:20.463658 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8202:tid 139867517064960] http://mysite.ru/en/uthuser/login/
>   [Sun Jan 28 18:52:20.463662 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8202:tid 139867517064960] /en/
>   [Sun Jan 28 18:52:20.463668 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8202:tid 139867517064960] http://mysite.ru/en/uthuser/login/
>   [Sun Jan 28 18:52:21.648818 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8202:tid 139867517064960] http://mysite.ru/en/uthuser/login/
>   [Sun Jan 28 18:52:21.648849 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8202:tid 139867517064960] /ru/
>   [Sun Jan 28 18:52:21.648859 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8202:tid 139867517064960] /ru/
>   id 8202:tid 139867550635776] /en/
>   [Sun Jan 28 18:52:37.358173 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8202:tid 139867550635776] http://mysite.ru/ru/uthuser/login/

ссылки типа /ru/  и /eng/  это я пытаюсь сменить язык но ничего не выходит :(

на тестовом сервере джанги все работает

вот кусок кода который использую в шаблонах, сразу скажу все теги закрыты все проверено и работает на тестовом сервере, просто не привожу весь код что бы не загромождать тему:

```
{% extends 'layouts/cp.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
   {% load static %}
{% load icotemplate %}
{% block content %}
        <div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h2>{% trans 'Dasboard' %}</h2>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="title-action">
                    <a href="{% url 'buyToken' %}" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans "By Tokens" %}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                                <div>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-right">
                                    <small></small>
                                        <br/>
```

код для смены языка:

```
# Функция смены языка сайта


def lang(request, lang):
    print(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    outplaceholder = str('/%s/' % lang)

    print(outplaceholder)
    if lang in dict(settings.LANGUAGES).keys():
        if url:
            url = str(url)
            for element in dict(settings.LANGUAGES):
                inplaceholder = str('/%s/' % element)
                # print(inplaceholder)
                url = re.sub(inplaceholder, outplaceholder, url)
                # print(url)
            return redirect(url)
        else:
            if hasattr(request, 'session'):

                request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = "en"

            return redirect("/en/")

    if hasattr(request, 'session'):
        request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = "en"

    return redirect("""/en/""")
```

Comment: Это всё не говорит вообще ни о чём. Покажите хотя бы какой-нибудь код, касающийся механизма смены языка, как оно у вас сделано-то

Comment: изменил шапку добавил кусок шаблона

Comment: Шаблоны по определению не могут менять язык. Вы не знаете как устроен ваш собственный сайт что ли?

Comment: добавил в шапку функцию смены языка по ссылке